# App getting crashed when completing Did Finish Picking ImagePicker Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using a Burst mode In my App Using *UIImagePickerController*, Once when I complete my App with More Number of Images taken The App is getting Crashed Showing Error:

`App quit Unexpectedly Terminated due to Memory Pressure`

```
 -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:    (NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [arrayImages addObject:image];
        if (picTaken) {
              [imagePicker takePicture];
    }
        else
             {

                [imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                 [self imagePlace];//Where i get All Images in a View presented same as in IOS camera Video//
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self      name:AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification object:nil];
             }];
        }
```

}

Comment: Reduced memory pressure using memory management techniques.

Comment: pls add the delegate method you defined for the completion

Comment: i have posted the code..but didnt get any reply...plz suggest some way that i can reduce the memory pressure problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is All related to memory as if your `iOS App` runs and When a `low memory condition` is detected on an `iOS device`, the virtual memory system sends out notifications asking applications to release memory. These notifications are sent to all running applications and processes, in an effort to reduce the total amount of memory in use.
If memory usage remains high, the system may terminate background processes to ease memory pressure. If enough memory can be freed, your application will continue to run and no crash report will be generated. Otherwise, your app will be terminated by `iOS`, and a low memory report will be generated. For More you can review [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs).

So you can use `Instruments` tool for resolving this problem and detect the memory usage and leakage and follow the memory management technique.